# Android: How to draw this custom shape

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-drawable, shapes

I'm new to Android, and I would like to know how to draw this blue shape:

[image]

Without using images, of course.

Thanks!

Comment: read about porter-duff stuff

Comment: so basically you have to call `Canvas#drawCircle` twice: the second time with a `Paint` which has set porter-duff Xfermode

Comment: Thank you, I will try that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way would be your suggested solution, ie. drawing all circles with no alpha to a bitmap, then draw that bitmap to another one using the desired alpha.
The hard way would be using blend modes, specifically [PorterDuff.Mode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html) in Android. An example can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/Xfermodes.html).

Also Check this http://softwyer.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/1009/

An example

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), b.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint p =  new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight()), borderRadius, borderRadius, p);
        p.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(b, 0, 0, p);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!